Webservice XML Deserialization Issue: double to decimal Conversion Error for Large Numbers
I am currently encountering an issue with a web service. The server-side field MinimumOrderAmount is of type double, and in my receiving program, I have defined it as decimal. When the server sends a value of 9999999999 for MinimumOrderAmount, my program throws an error with the following message:
Exception thrown passed to this Web service: System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (1, 3998). ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseDecimal(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderAvailabilityService.Read13_VoucherDiscount(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderAvailabilityService.Read90_RoomRate(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderAvailabilityService.Read141_RoomStay(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderAvailabilityService.Read142_AvailResponseSegment(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderAvailabilityService.Read143_AvailabilityResponse(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderAvailabilityService.Read191_AvailabilityResponse()
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)

Theoretically, a double type should be able to be directly converted to a decimal type. Why does this conversion fail when the value is 9999999999, but succeeds when the value is 999999999 (9 digits)?
When I encountered this issue, I tried changing the data type of the MinimumOrderAmount field on the server side from double to decimal. After making this change, I was able to receive the value correctly, even when its length exceeded 10 digits.

In the web service server, a method was published to query prices. This method includes a field named MinimumOrderAmount, which was defined as a double type on the server side. On my side, instead of using a tool to generate the code, I manually added the field and defined it as a decimal type.
When the server returns the following XML message:
<VoucherDiscount voucherNo="24007-23178c98426a491b30fd7db155e16662" minimumOrderAmount="9999999999.0" currency="USD">
<DiscountAmount currencyCode="USD" decimals="2">1000</DiscountAmount>
<TotalAfterDiscount currencyCode="USD" decimals="2">2721.66</TotalAfterDiscount>
<TotalTaxAfterDiscount currencyCode="USD" decimals="2">278.34</TotalTaxAfterDiscount>
</VoucherDiscount>

I encountered an error while receiving this data.
Here is the code I used to receive the data:
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.233")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://webservices.micros.com/og/4.3/HotelCommon/")]
public partial class VoucherDiscount : VoucherDiscountBasic
{
    [XmlAttribute("minimumOrderAmount")]
    public decimal MinimumOrderAmount { get; set; }
    public Amount DiscountAmount { get; set; }
    public Amount TotalAfterDiscount { get; set; }
    public Amount TotalTaxAfterDiscount { get; set; }
}

